# Does adding 'readonly' attribute to jquery ui datepicker affect its accessibility?

Tags: html, jquery-ui, datepicker, accessibility

I'm using the jquery UI datepicker control but do not want the 'keyboard' to display on mobile/tablet when a user clicks on the input field.

A way to prevent this is to add 'readyonly=readonly' to the input.

However, I'm concerned that this will negatively affect accessibility.

Will users, using a screen reader, still be able to edit the field / select a date.

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes, it will be very difficult for visually impaired users to select a date.

In terms of screen readers, the experience will not too different if they are using NVDA and WindowEyes. Because these screen readers don't announce whether a text input is read-only or not. However, JAWS does announce if a field is read only. So it's a mixed bag and may cause confusion for some users.

But, more importantly, you should be aware that many blind users rely on keyboard to enter dates; picking a date from a table is a tedious task for them. So, disabling the keyboard may not be an ideal solution.

In my opinion it is best use a date picker icon instead of relying on the focus event. This way, sighted users can click on the icon to display the picker without ever displaying the keyboard.

Comment: would it help if the 'readonly' attribute is only present on mobile and tablet devices? (i'm assuming, either rightly or wrongly that blind users will only be using a desktop or laptop device). And that partially sighted users would be able to use the datepicker - if they were able to use a tablet or mobile?

Comment: Visually impaired users do use mobile devices, including touch screens of all sizes. Both iOS and Android now ship with built-in screen readers. In my opinion, partially sighted users will not have too much difficulty using the datepicker (since they mostly use screen magnifiers), however fully blind users will have great difficulty in both cases if keyboard is disabled.

Comment: This is a real tricky one for me. As making the input clickable (and hiding the keyboard) is arguably better for the majority of people who wouldn't use the keyboard. As the keyboard is laborious and you have to put the date in, in a precise format. So keeping the keyboard hinders usability for the majority. But i can't think of a way to retain that functionality for disabled users / provide an alternative.