# How to make certain dates unavailable within html date form

Tags: jquery, html, datetime, jquery-ui-datepicker, forms

I have a booking form from which I have a date form. I would like to disable certain days that is booked/unavailable. I have JavaScript code which doesn't work in my case. Is there any other way that could help me disable dates within the calendar?

```js
var array = ["2019-03-14", "2019-03-11", "2019-03-26"];

$(function () {
  $('input').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
      return [array.indexOf(string) == -1]
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="date">Book your date</label>
  <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" placeholder="" required readonly>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code appears to be working pretty well. The only thing I changed below is:

- added a `dateFormat` option of `yy-mm-dd`, as this is the format that an `<input type="date">` requires,
- marked the input as `readonly` so it can only be modified through the popin (note that this might not be ideal accessibility-wise).

```js
var array = ["2019-03-14", "2019-03-11", "2019-03-26"];

$(function () {
  $('input').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
      return [array.indexOf(string) == -1]
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="date">Book your date</label>
  <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" placeholder="" required readonly>
</div>
```

Comment: @charly As you can see by running the snippet I posted (blue button), it doesn't prevent you from picking dates.

Comment: Do apologise , i had a little typo in my date form , now it works fine . you said it this might not be idea accessibility wise. what would be alternative / better way of handling this for booking dates by people?

Comment: @charly See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941088/does-adding-readonly-attribute-to-jquery-ui-datepicker-affect-its-accessibilit). I'd say the best way would be to not use `readonly` at all and validate the value like you would any other field (through I'm not sure you could validate against a blacklist of days using HTML5 standard attributes). Anyway, not my specialty, but I'm confident you can find information about it.

Comment: also   i am  using this to disable time   , but i am still able to pick the time . any idea why ?                                                                                                                                        $('#disableTimeRangesExample').timepicker({
    'disableTimeRanges': [
        ['1am', '2am'],
        ['3am', '4:01am']
    ]
});

Comment: @charly What timepicker plugin are you using? Doesn't seem like anything standard (not part of jQuery UI). Anyway, better create another question for it.

Comment: i have a problem , when i click on any other forms , like name , time . the date calendar pops up why is that ?

Comment: You're applying the `datepicker` plugin to all `input` elements. Use a class to mark only the controls that need a Date Picker and use that.

Comment: @HereticMonkey  Thank you for your comment , you're right.  so within the form i made an id="inputdate"  , and i applied the datepicker to the id  $('#inputdate').datepicker  . is my approach correct?

Comment: @charly Sure, if you have a single element that needs the datepicker, using an id is fine.

Answer (score 0):

please add this anywhere in between `<head> </head>` :

```
  <!-- datepicker -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <!-- //datepicker -->
```

Comment: Why do you need three different versions of jQuery and jQuery UI?